# Using a PHP include for <head> to provide CSS is giving mixed results

Tags: php, html, css, include

I want to use a PHP include for the  section. I have an index.php and a head.html in which I have the usual stuff: title, etc plus a link to bootstrap CDN, and a custom CSS file.

Upon testing, the styles from Bootstrap work fine but my custom overrides aren't. I was under the impression custom CSS files automatically override bootstrap? This has worked for me in the past when linking to them traditionally on every page of the website. However, I want to use PHP includes to save time.

I've played around with the order of things (i.e. Bootstrap first, custom CSS first etc), I've tried linking to the custom CSS file separately (outside the include) but can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

My code below:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include("includes/head.html");?>

</head>

<body>

<div class="jumbotron paral paralsec">
    <h1 class="hero-heading display-3 text-dark">Some text.</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

head.html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

<title>Site Title</title>

<!-- Bootstrap CDN below -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom CSS below -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/customCSS.css">

<!-- Font Awesome below -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 

<!-- Google Fonts below -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#">
```

customCSS.css (only contains one h1 style, for testing)

```
h1 {color: white}
```

Folder structure:

```
CSS (Folder)
    customCSS.css
includes (Folder)
    head.html
index.php
```

Comment: Not sure what else is going wrong, but definitely do custom CSS after Bootstrap.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] to show us?

Comment: As in, do custom CSS after bootstrap inside the head.html file that's then included via PHP? Or do custom CSS link after include in index.php?

Comment: I think either way should be okay, as long as the custom ends up in the page source after so that it will be loaded after. Have you checked the with browser dev tools to make sure that the custom files are definitely being loaded at all?

Comment: Code added to OP. @Don't Panic, they appear not to be loaded at all.

Comment: Your custom css is linked using an incorrect relative path. Please add your url or folder structure to the question to get a for a solution

Comment: You can check the network tab in your browser dev tools to see where it's trying to load them from. That should give you an idea of how you need to adjust the paths.

Comment: Folder structure added - sorry if it's not presented well. :S

Comment: No, someone just edited that., the index.php is in the same level as the includes folder. So, I have 'CSS' folder, 'includes' folder and index.php, then within the includes folder I have 'head.html' and within the CSS folder I have 'customCSS.css'.

Comment: I've just checked the network tab on developer tools and the customCSS file is being loaded, but not actioned.

Comment: In that case, see the answer below. Bootstrap has a more specific style for that h1, or some of the specific classes you've applied to it are overriding the more general style.

Comment: the php `include()` with non-php contents is nothing more than copy&paste. You can safely get it out of the issue here.

Comment: I've tested things further. The <h1> style was just for illustration so specificity isn't the issue. For some reason my localhost is intermittently seeing the customCSS file then not. Then, when it does, it is seeing and older version of it with irrelevant code. I've restarted everything, moved all the files out then in again. I can edit index.php and see edits immediately but for some reason the CSS files is still showing an old version... :S

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of CSS files plays a less important role than most people think.

When there are multiple rules targeting the same thing, specificity is the most important factor. Higher specificity almost always wins.

When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule (last one called) is the one that usually gets applied.

There's a lot more info on this topic here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suggestions.

It turns out I was experiencing a CSS caching issue. My browser was auto-loading an outdated version of the CSS file. The PHP include and and CSS link were working normally.

If any others come across this thread and are looking for the solution, see here:
https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Thanks again
Tom